# When do variables get copied when being passed as arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is reference implemented internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954764/how-is-reference-implemented-internally)

```
void f (int& a)
{
    a ++;
}

int main ()
{
    int b = 5;
    f(b);
    cout << b << endl; //prints 6
}
```

When I saw the syntax for references in C++, it initially looked like the variable b (if it were an object) would be copied into f. How do these references actually work under the hood? (Some simple asm would be great.)

Comment: References are simply aliases to the original variable.Any modification on a reference will modify the variable being referred.There is no copying involved.The exact detail of how references are implemented is **Unspecified** by the standard.Having said that under the hood most compilers simply use pointers for implementing references.

Comment: Your compiler will give you sample asm -- find the options for outputting unassembled code or the tools for disassembling its binary output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the pass-by-reference most likely uses pointer semantics - i.e. the address of the object is probably passed as the parameter.\

> When I saw the syntax for references in C++, it initially looked like the variable b (if it were an object) would be copied into f.

Nope. That's one of the upsides of references - no copying.

```
    f(b);
00DF1405  lea         eax,[b]  
00DF1408  push        eax  
00DF1409  call        f (0DF1177h)  
00DF140E  add         esp,4
```

`eax` will contain the address of `b`, and is then pushed onto the function argument stack.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood in C++ references implemented exactly like pointers. The only difference is some compile time checks and different syntax.
So in your case function f gets a "pointer" to integer b and increments the value of b.