# C++ How reference works behind the scenes

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

For example in

```
int *a = 5;
MyFunc(&a);
```

What are the behind the scenes working of '&' Is it just creating a pointer to the pointer and deferencing it automatically? or is it doing something different.

Is there any way to pass by "true" reference in C++ or will everything be a pointer passed by value?

Comment: I don't see any references here. `&a` is not a reference, it is an address of `a`, it has type `int**`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

References in C++ are basically implemented as pointers.  I would assume that's how they're implemented in all languages, not just C++.

There's an earlier question with better answers here:  [How is reference implemented internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954764/how-is-reference-implemented-internally)