# Passing a pointer as a parameter leads to opposite results

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, reference

I am new to C++, and I am wondering why, when we pass an array's address as an argument to a function and the function's parameter is declared a pointer, we do not have to dereference the array in the function itself?

Please take a look at the following reproducible example.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

bool printArrByPointer(char* theString);
int main() {
    char str[255]; // setting an array 
    /*
        Notice:
            When I remove "cin.getline()" then I get an actual address to str which is what I expected.
            However, when I put the "cin.getline()", I somehow get the actual value of the string and I don't
            know why this is because str should be an array and just an array should yield an address.
            If we filled str by putting user input, will not str still yield an address? 
    */
    cin.getline(str, 255); // reading the string
    printArrByPointer(str); // passing the (what I expect to be) a pointer
    return 0;
}

bool printArrByPointer(char* theString) { // a pointer declaration as a parameter
    cout << theString; // shouldn't printing theString yield a pointer?
    return true;
}
```

In [passing pointers as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054662/why-do-certain-c-c-functions-use-pointers-as-parameters), the answers did not use characters and I have a strong feeling that why I am getting unexpected results is because of the `cin.getline()` function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just about every time someone wants to print a `char *` they want the string it's pointing at, so operator `<<`  has an overload that prints the string rather than the value of the pointer.

Comment: Looks like someone is teaching you "C". In C++ you really should be using `std::string` or `std::string_view`. Using pointers to represent an array is just a road to bugs (out of bound memory access, memory leaks etc)

Comment: What output do you consider to be "an actual address"?

Comment: I had it added to the list of duplicates, but on second thought its not really a duplicate. Nevertheless related and I suggest to read https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/4117728. Though, while digging into correct use of c-arrays in c++ you should not neglect proper use of c++ arrays in c++, that is `std::string` for strings, `std::array` for fixed and `std::vector` for dynamically sized

Comment: ps: `str` is an array. It is not a pointer. But that array decays to a pointer to first element when you pass it to the function `printArrByPointer(str);`. For details see q&a in previous comment

Comment: This is my go-to interview question! What's the difference between `int arr[]` and `int* arr`? Nothing!  A C-style array *is* a pointer and `arr[2]` === `*(arr + 2*sizeof(int)`.  So when you pass an array into a function, you *are* passing in a pointer.  `cout << (char*)arr` prints out the byte-value  `*arr` and continues until it gets to a zero-byte... the C-string.

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN You might want to reword *A C-style array is a pointer* because an array isn't a pointer. `int arr[]` and `int*` are are the same because `int arr[]` isn't an array.

Comment: Agreed, when `int arr[255];` is declared, the equivalent statement is `int* arr; arr=malloc(sizeof(int) * 255);`  so, in that way, `arr` is a pointer to `arr[0]`'s address, but... it's an array and not a "pointer", it is an array.  This extra work done at initialization and the `free` that is all going to be handled by the compiler, it's best not to completely mix the ideas in your head.

Comment: `cout << static_cast<void const*>(theString);` to print the pointer value.

Comment: @Eljay you don't need the `const` since `theString` is not `const` to begin with: `cout << static_cast<void*>(theString);` Yes, `operator<<` takes a `const void*`, but you can pass a non-const `void*` to it

Comment: @RemyLebeau • Habit.  C++: all the defaults are wrong.

Comment: "it's an array and not a "pointer", it is an array" no. In your example `arr` is a pointer to first element of an array. It is not an array. Confusing the two leads to all kinds of bugs and more confusion. In a function declaration there is no difference between `int arr[]` and `int* arr`, but just because arrays can decay does not mean that arrays and pointers are the same