# Calling derived function from a derived function of another class

Tags: c++

I have two base classes `Vehicle` and `WorkerUnit` and they have derived classes `Bus` and `Maintenance` respectively.

The `Maintenance` class has to be initialized with a variable of class `Vehicle` (or the derived classes of `Vehicle`), and the function `print()` inside class `Bus` is to be called. How do I achieve this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Vehicle Class
class Vehicle {
public:
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "Vehicle print() called" << endl;
    }
};

class Bus : public Vehicle {
public:
    void print() {
        Vehicle::print();
        cout << "   Bus print() called" << endl;
    }
};

// Worker Unit Class
class WorkerUnit {
protected:
    Vehicle vehicle;
public:
    WorkerUnit(Vehicle vehicle) : vehicle(vehicle) {}
    virtual void print() {}
};

class Maintenance : public WorkerUnit {
public:
    Maintenance(Vehicle vehicle) : WorkerUnit(vehicle) {}
    void print() {
        // Problem here where function calls base class Vehicle's print()
        // How do I actually call the derived class's print()?
        vehicle.print();
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Bus *bus = new Bus();
    Maintenance *m = new Maintenance(*bus);
    m->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223613/c-polymorphism-without-pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references

Comment: @LogicStuff Thanks for the quick reply. I've never really encountered this until now.