# Why does this function accept a `const char*` as a parameter instead just `char*`?

Tags: c, function, pointers

Noob C questions incoming:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
int 
getaddrinfo(const char *hostname, const char *servname, const struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **res)

void 
freeaddrinfo(struct addrinfo *ai)
```

Taken from http://www.nxmnpg.com/3/getaddrinfo. Namely I'm interested in why it isn't just getaddrinfo(char *hostname) and is a const instead.

I have an idea what a pointer is. It seems to me that almost all of the functions in C prefer pointers passed to just variables, is this correct?

Comment: For pointers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers

Comment: You're asking two different questions: why the `const`, and why to use pointers.

Answer (score 3):

The `const` qualifier is a contract the function is making with you ensuring you that it **will not** change the value of any `const` arguments passed to it.  This can be verified by the compiler so it's a good way to add extra safey and reassurance for you at the end of a long morning (;

Comment: Plus, in certain cases it can allow the code generator to perform additional optimizations.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: `const` in C doesn't provide much of anything for optimizations. Aliasing issues generally prevent a compiler from assuming that a pointer-to-const won't change, and as far as non-pointer related `const` goes - if a variable isn't changed in a function, the compiler is generally free to optimize it the same way, whether it's annotated as `const` or not (in other words, `const` doesn't add anything as far as optimizaibilty goes).

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have the concept of a string as a basic type; it's an array of `(char)`, which can only be passed to a function as a pointer to `(char)`.  You will also see `(long)` passed as a pointer in older APIs, dating back to when many of the CPUs on which C was implemented couldn't pass a `(long)` in a register (thus couldn't be `return`ed).