# The Arrow Member Operator in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

I am quite new to using C++. I have handled Java and ActionScript before, but now I want to learn this powerful language. Since C++ grants the programmer the ability to explicitly use pointers, I am quite confused over the use of the arrow member operator. Here is a sample code I tried writing.

main.cpp:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "Arrow.h"
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
        Arrow object;
        Arrow *pter = &object;

        object.printCrap(); //Using Dot Access
        pter->printCrap(); //Using Arrow Member Operator
        return 0;
   }
```

Arrow.cpp

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "Arrow.h"
   using namespace std;

   Arrow::Arrow()
   {

   }

   void Arrow::printCrap(){
       cout << "Steak!" << endl;
   }
```

In the above code, all it does is to print steak, using both methods (Dot and Arrow).

In short, in writing a real practical application using C++, when do I use the arrow notation? I’m used to using the dot notation due to my previous programming experience, but the arrow is completely new to me.

Comment: The arrow is just the pointer's version of the dot. Sometimes you'll need pointers, so that's when you use it. Most of the time, a smart pointer would better suit you than a raw one, though.

Comment: This provides some additional insight.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/c-when-to-use-references-vs-pointers

Comment: From your question it seems clear that you know the answer already: Use the arrow when dealing with pointers to objects, rather than objects or references to objects. Perhaps the real questions is: When to use a pointer? There are questions about that already, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/c-when-to-use-references-vs-pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good Question,

> **Dot(.)**  this operator is used for accessing the member function or
>   sometime the data member of a class or structure using instance
>   variable of that class/Structure.

```
object.function(); 
object.dataMember; //not a standard for class.
```

> **arrow(->)** this operator is used for accessing the member function or
>   sometime the data member of a class or structure but using pointer of
>   that class/Structure.

```
ptr->function();
ptr->datamember; //not a standard for class.
```

Comment: Also worth noting: if `p` is a pointer that points to object `o`, then `p->blah` is exactly equivalent to `(*p).blah`, which is eqivalent to `o.blah`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: unless `->` is overloaded

Comment: @newacct - correct me if I'm wrong, but `->` cannot be overloaded for a pointer, only for a class.

Comment: @Robᵩ please check with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading.

Answer (score 7):

In C, `a->b` is precisely equivalent to `(*a).b`. The "arrow" notation was introduced as a convenience; accessing a member of a struct via a pointer was fairly common and the arrow notation is easier to write/type, and generally considered more readable as well.

C++ adds another wrinkle as well though: `operator->` can be overloaded for a `struct`/`class`. Although fairly unusual otherwise, doing so is common (nearly required) for smart pointer classes.

That's not really unusual in itself: C++ allows the vast majority of operators to be overloaded (although some almost never *should* be, such as `operator&&`, `operator||` and `operator,`).

What is unusual is how an overloaded `operator->` is interpreted. First, although `a->b` looks like `->` is a binary operator, when you overload it in C++, it's treated as a unary operator, so the correct signature is `T::operator()`, not `T::operator(U)` or something on that order.

The result is interpreted somewhat unusually as well. Assuming `foo` is an object of some type that overloads `operator->`, `foo->bar` is interpreted as meaning `(f.operator->())->bar`. That, in turn, restricts the return type of an overloaded `operator->`. Specifically, it must return either an instance of *another* class that also overloads `operator->` (or a reference to such an object) or else it must return a pointer.

In the former case, a simple-looking `foo->bar` could actually mean "chasing" through an entire (arbitrarily long) chain of instances of objects, each of which overloads `operator->`, until one is finally reached that can refer to a member named `bar`. For an (admittedly extreme) example, consider this:

```
#include <iostream>

class int_proxy {
    int val;
public:
    int_proxy(): val(0) {}
    int_proxy &operator=(int n) { 
        std::cout<<"int_proxy::operator= called\n";
        val=n; 
        return *this; 
    }
};

struct fubar {
    int_proxy bar;
} instance;

struct h {
    fubar *operator->() {
        std::cout<<"used h::operator->\n";
        return &instance;
    }
};

struct g {
    h operator->() {
        std::cout<<"used g::operator->\n";
        return h();   
    }
};

struct f {
    g operator->() { 
        std::cout<<"Used f::operator->\n";
        return g();
    }
};

int main() {
    f foo;

    foo->bar=1;
}
```

Even though `foo->bar=1;` looks like a simple assignment to a member via a pointer, this program actually produces the following output:

```
Used f::operator->
used g::operator->
used h::operator->
int_proxy::operator= called
```

Clearly, in this case `foo->bar` is *not* (even close to) equivalent to a simple `(*foo).bar`. As is obvious from the output, the compiler generates "hidden" code to walk through the whole series of overloaded `->` operators in various classes to get from `foo` to (a pointer to) something that has a member named `bar` (which in this case is also a type that overloads `operator=`, so we can see output from the assignment as well).

Comment: Great addition here. Between your answer and YS's answer, nearly everyone should have what they need. Now if we could get search engines to return results for symbols like '->'...

Comment: @noloader: You might want to take a look at [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The -> operator is a way of calling a member function of the pointer that is being dereferenced. It can also be written as (*pter).printCap(). C++ is difficult to learn without a class or book so I recommend getting one, it'll be a great investement!