# Why do we use pointers instead of local variables?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers

I don't understand the difference between using a pointer and using a normal variable. I'm learning linked lists in class so the use of pointers seems more straightforward since pointers are used to go to the next node in the list, but I don't understand its more basic uses and I'm feeling stressed as it is something I should already understand but don't.

Comment: We don't normally use pointers unless we have to.

Comment: take a look at this, it might help clear your head a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers

Comment: yes but I don't understand what a pointer does that a variable doesn't do

Comment: `closed as not constructive`. I'll never understand this.

Comment: The question makes no sense. Pointers are ordinary variables, meaning that they can easily be *local* variables. The question contraposes "pointers" and "local variables" as something mutually exclusive.

Comment: If you don't understand the difference between a pointer and an `int` variable, for example, then you don't understand pointers yet. I suggest you take some further readings to make it clear.

Comment: We use pointers when we need to point to something. That's what they do.

Comment: Ask your teacher for help, sooner rather than later.

Comment: @GManNickG: I think a book will be a better option. I mean person that teaches language, doesn't necessarily use that language.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer is in itself just a "normal" variable that just so happens to store a level of indirection to another variable.