# How big should a structure be before you should start using a pointer to it, rather than making a copy? [C]

Tags: c, pointers

This is a slightly subjective answer, but how large do you think a structure should be before you start using pointers to it in other structures or function calls rather than the structure by-value?

Comment: Profile, profile, profile. It's too dependent on too many factors to say for sure what the answer is.

Comment: mostly, the usage depends on the requirement type, like whether you want to change the contents of that structure from the child function or not.

Comment: shuttle87: C, sorry, changed the tags.

Comment: How long should a piece of string be before you need a reel? Clearly, it depends on a lot of things.

Comment: Premature micro-optimization. Write good code first, then optimize where necessary.

Comment: When you first start to notice problems.

Comment: related: [Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the compiler and architecture.
C and C++ define the size of the types they use, and how functions are written, but they don't define how they are implemented.
This is means the standard itself doesn't define how the structurs are passed, just that they are in essence copied.
The compiler might decide to do something else entirely, like not copying the struct at all if there's a default copy constructor , and the variable isn't used.

But after saying all that, most common-sense compiler implementations would store the struct in a register if it fits.  So depends on the architecture, make sure the structure fits in a register.

Comment: I think, you should add the info about size of registers on common architectures to your post.

Comment: Umm.. Think about that. We had `8-bit` computing for a while, then **8086** `16-bit` computing, then **80386** `32-bit` computing and now **IA-64** or **AMD64** `64-bit` computing. I wonder what the `bits` are measuring?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think, to someone it may be not that obvious.

Comment: 64 bit processors aren't limited to 64 bit registers. CPUs that support SSE2 support 128 bit registers, and AVX (SSE4) support 256 bit registers.