# Is there something you can do, that the only way is using pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

So I know that on C pointers can do pretty neat stuff.
But C++ is object oriented. I can refer to an object instead of using pointers. Am I right? So why having pointers in C++?
I can understand that pointers might be implemented for compatibility reasons. Pointers were the power of C. Okay. But really, is there something you can do in C++ and the **only (or best)** way is using pointers?

Can you give me a good example?

To make it more clear:
Is there something in C++ that I can be done only by using pointer?
Can I avoid pointers and still do everything someone who uses pointers can do in C++?

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers

Comment: @ChrisDrew Polymorphism also works through references.  But of course, references are sort of like a restricted form of pointers, and in practice, polymorphism will usually entail dynamic allocation, which in turn requires pointers.

Comment: Make the lifetime of an object independent of the scope in which it was instantiated.

Comment: I think that a linked-list is a pretty simple example of something that you can't implement without pointers.

Comment: ...Also - leak memory.  ;-)

Comment: Added this to the main body and also copy pasting here: To make it more clear: Is there something in C++ that I can be done only by using pointer? Can I avoid pointers and still do everything someone who uses pointers can do in C++?

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner You don't need pointers to leak memory; in fact, you need pointers to not leak memory, since `delete` requires a pointer argument.  (But of course, `this` is a pointer, so anytime you have a member function, you have pointers.)

Comment: @JamesKanze can you give an example of memory leaking program without using pointers or constructs returning pointers?

Comment: Grim that you said about instance lifetime is also interesting.

Comment: @Erbureth Obviously, you need a `new`.  But if you don't assign the results to a pointer, it may leak.  (Of course, the constructor may assign `this` to a pointer elsewhere, so that it doesn't leak.)  Pointers don't cause memory leaks, dynamic allocation can.

Comment: @Ebureth Well, if you wrote exactly this line of code `new int(0);` then arguably it's a "leak without pointers" as the return from new (a pointer) is never stored.

Comment: @GeorgeEco it was going to form part of an answer, but the question is locked out.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, polymorphism only works when accessing through
pointers or references.  More generally, any sort of a dynamic
structure (graphs, etc.) will require pointers, and it's almost
always necessary to be able to navagate between objects, which
also requires pointers.  In fact, the desire to use OO
techniques is often the main reason behind a lot of pointers in
C++.

You might note that “pure” OO languages generally
require that everything be a pointer, for exactly these reasons.

Comment: I mean is there any other way to use a graph or will you need a pointer for sure? If graphs for instance MUST use pointers, your answer solves my question.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for giving me a guideline to search further.
I accept this as the best answer.

Comment: @GeorgeEco I can't think of any way of implementing a graph without pointers.  I can't think of any way of navigating between objects without pointers either.  (Of course, you can view the navigation links as edges in a graph.)

Comment: Case solved. I was looking for a good example on this topic and here you are giving me the answer! Thank you James!

Comment: @JamesKanze: You can implement dynamic data structures as elements in an array. Just replace the pointers with indexes.

Comment: @Blastfurnace OK.  In that sense, you don't need pointers; just put all your data into an array, and use indexes.  (In some sense, that's what happens at the hardware level anyway, at least most of the time.  Your memory is just one big array, and a pointer is an index into it.)

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit broad and philosophical. In fact, it is impossible to completely omit pointers, as usually the used API demands it (e.g. the arguments of the `main` function). If pointers are not necessary for a specific fixed technical reason, theoretically it would not be necessary to use pointers.

However, this statement is to be taken *cum grano salis*; if no pointers are used, it is impossible to have dynamic memory management, allocation and deallocation. On the other hand, if usage of the STL is permitted, all of this is nicely encapsulated; pointers would not be involved except for the used APIs, inside the STL and in the definition of the `main` function.