# Qt child qmainwindow disappear at pop out

Tags: c++, qt

I have one button on `MainWindow` to show another `QMainWindow`.

```
void MainWindow::viewSecondWindow()
{
    QMainWindow w = new QMainWindow(this);
    w.show();
}
```

The code got compiled well and ran succesfully. However if I click on the button , the second window does pop out but it automatically closes.

**Edit :**

For the future people who face similiar situation, please refer to this.
[Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers)

Comment: Did you mean QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow(this); actually?

Comment: hi @demonplus, that just solved my problem. Thank you so much. I'm very new to c++. If you could write ur answer below I will mark it as accepted. Thanks again. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following instead:

```
QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow(this);
```

Because otherwise `w` will be destroyed immediately after `show()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use QDialog in
place of Mainwindow

Comment: How will QDialog help him if he needs to create QMainWindow ?