# why use Pointer on single variable

Tags: c, pointers

please explain exactly why do i use **pointer** on non array variable such as `int` i know pointer variable store the address of specified variable but why do we need address of just single variable, what is the advantage of doing this?

`int a = 10;`

`int *ptr_a = &a;`

Thanks!

Comment: Read the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers

Comment: Ask the author of the code. The code in the question is pointless. Is there context?

Answer (score 0):

Although I guess the code you're looking at should give you an answer ... the typical reason this is done is for passing it to a function that should be able to modify this variable.

if you just call `foo(a)`, the function `foo()` will receive the *value of the variable* as an argument, so it has it's own copy. The same thing happens with a pointer, but the pointer will of course still point to your original variable, so the function could modify it by dereferencing the pointer (`*a = 42;`).

Answer (score 0):

By using pointer we achieve **call by reference** mechanism 
please compile below snippet by removing the pointer and note the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *a,int *b);
int main(){
  int num1=5,num2=10;
  swap(&num1,&num2);  /* address of num1 and num2 is passed to swap function */
  printf("Number1 = %d\n",num1);
  printf("Number2 = %d",num2);
  return 0;
}

void swap(int *a,int *b){ /* pointer a and b points to address of num1 and num2 respectively */
  int temp;
  temp=*a;
  *a=*b;
  *b=temp;
}
```

**Explanation:**
The address of memory location `num1 and num2` are passed to function and the pointers `*a and *b` accept those values. So, the pointer a and b points to address of num1 and num2 respectively. When, the value of pointer are changed, the value in memory location also changed correspondingly. Hence, change made to `*a and *b` was reflected in `num1 and num2` in main function.

This technique is known as call by reference in C programming.

Comment: *This technique is known as call by reference in C programming.* No it is not. C does not support call by reference. This is passing an address by value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but in this link  http://www.javatpoint.com/call-by-value-and-call-by-reference-in-c  clearly mention call by reference

Comment: C does not have call by reference, only call by value, a very well known fact

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok ,but can u provide me some resources where i can read about that

Comment: Just do a Web search for these terms

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the link above shared found while search the web but here they mentioned it call by reference

Comment: It's a way to simulate call by reference. It's an address passed by value, formally.

Comment: Oh my ... this discussion could easily be more productive by getting to the point: "This technique allows you to have call by reference *semantics* in C". Yes, C itself is call by value *only*, passing a pointer (by value, of course) is the way to get around it.