# Initializing by pointer in c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, initialization

So let's say I have a class `MyClass`. Now I want to use another class called `Animals`, I would probably do the following.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
private:
    Animals animals;
};
```

However I can also do this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
private:
    Animals* animals;
};
```

and then initialize the class in the constructor with:

```
animals = new Animals();
```

What is the difference between the two different approaches, which is better and why? In my use `Animals` should only be used inside `MyClass`. My question is mainly about **performance** and **memory**, I mean is initializing by pointer requires more resources or not?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Can you specify your question down a little bit

Comment: Looks like you need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers)

Comment: @TankorSmash it's not a homework question, but I will try to improve my question

Comment: Maybe you could try specifying how you're looking to use animals as a pointer or something, and explain the problem you ran into by doing it that way. Right now its so broad it's hard to answer effectively.

Comment: Allocating with `new` gives you a pointer to an object created on the heap. The first method pre-allocates memory as part of the parent structure. If you allocate via `new` you *must* free that memory eventually.

Comment: You should prefer the initialization list of the ctor over the ctor body.

Answer (score 5):

If you consider how memory is managed in a class it should become clear. When you declare `Animals animal` in your class, then space is reserved for `animal` in the memory footprint of your class. But when you declare `Animals* animal` only a pointer to `Animal` is reserved in the memory footprint of your class.

Neither is better, as it depends on your circumstances. If you are always going to create an animal and `MyClass` owns it, then use the first approach as it will only require one memory allocation. If `animals` can often be empty and memory is a concern then you might want to use the second approach.

Incidentally if you are using C++11 or above, you might want to consider `std::unique_ptr<Animal>` for the second case.

Answer (score 1):

If the sole existence of the `animals` object depend on the `MyClass` object, then use **containment**:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
private:
    Animals animals;
};
```

If the existence of `animals` is independent, but `MyClass` want to maintain an association to it, then use **pointer**:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
private:
    Animals * animals;
};
```

The choice depends on the object ownership model.

There are many considerations involved.

In the containment approach, the memory for `animals` is allocated along with the `MyClass` object. They always go together and `MyClass` fully **owns** `animals`.

In the pointer approach, they are two separate pieces of memory and need to be allocated separately. It is an association without any ownership. Throughout the lifetime of `MyClass`, multiple things may happen:

- `myclass` does not associate to any `Animals`, i.e. `animals = nullptr`
- `myclass` may associate to different `Animals` at different time, i.e. `animals = a1; /* ... */; animals = a2;`

Moreover multiple objects, either `MyClass` objects or other type of objects`, may hold the same`animals` pointer.

If the `animals` object is destroyed, then these objects have a risk of using the stale pointer, hence some mechanism is necessary to avoid that.

With pointer approach, one can use run time polymorphism which is not possible in the containment approach. For example

```
void MyClass::setAnimal(Animal * a) {
  animal = a;
}

Animal * a1 = new Lion;
Animal * a2 = new Tiger;

MyClass x1;
x1.setAnimal(a1);

MyClass x2;
x2.setAnimal(a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

From a design point of view, `MyClass` is a container of one `Animal`. In the first example you always have an `Animal`. In the second example you may or may not have an `Animal`.

For example if you have a cage with a bird, your first cage always has a bird and it can not be empty of a bird, but the second example you may or may not have a bird.

This is called `Cardinality` (0, 1) in databases. You can think of it like having an collection of `Animals`, with one or zero elements (even tough you don't have an array).

The second aspect is that, in the first example, you always have the same `Animal`, and you can't pass around it freely and the lifetime of the `Animal` depends exclusively on the container. The second example allows to move the `Animal` to a new container or to have the same `Animal` in two different containers and to decouple the life of the `Animal` from the container.

Then, with C++, you have to consider memory allocation and ownership, where we usually use smart pointers to deallocate the Animal.