# Changing a pointer's value

Tags: c, pointers

I just started learning C language and i have a basic question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // These variables have been assigned hidden values:
    int secret;
    int *another_secret;

    // Declare a variable named secret_pt and make it point to secret:

    // Add the value at the address pointed to by another_secret to the
    // value at the address pointed to by secret_pt.
    // Do not change the address assigned to secret_pt, and don't explicitly set secret.

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my approach;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // These variables have been assigned hidden values:
    int secret;
    int *another_secret;

    // Declare a variable named secret_pt and make it point to secret:

     //  int *secret_pt;
    //secret_pt = &secret;
    int *secret_pt = &secret;

    // Add the value at the address pointed to by another_secret to the
    // value at the address pointed to by secret_pt.
    // Do not change the address assigned to secret_pt, and don't explicitly set secret.

    int *secret = *another_secret;

    return 0;
}
```

But i'm getting redefining error which makes sense but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Reread the error. You already have a variable named `secret`, of type `int` - and now you're declaring a variable named `secret` of type `int *`.

Comment: That's a homework question and it looks more like a problem understanding the text than a programming question. I'd recommend to aask your tutor to explain what he means (although it is quite clear). Note the code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I read it as `*secret_pt += *another_secret`. `secret` is an `int`, not a pointer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist right, I meant `int sum = *secret_pt + *another_secret;` I'm pretty sure the point is to illustrate dereferencing pointers, given the verbiage "Add the *value at the address pointed to by* another_secret"

Answer (score 0):

You are given two addresses, `secret_pt` and `another_secret`. You are asked to add their contents together and store the result into whatever `secret_pt` points to. This happens to be `secret`, but you are not supposed to assign to it directly.

The contents of a pointer is accessed by dereferencing it using the `*` operator. So the value at the address of `secret_pt` is `*secret_pt` and similarly the value at the address of `another_secret` is `*another_secret`. You can add them together.

Keep in mind that `*secret_pt` is just `secret`, a fact that you can use to store into `secret` without actually using the name `secret`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), Welcome to [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers)

> A fundamental C++ rule that states that no translation unit shall
>   contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class
>   type, enumeration type or template, and that every program shall
>   contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or
>   variable. Some definitions may be duplicated in multiple translation
>   units, subject to strict rules.

*ISO/IEC 14882-2014. Programming Languages — C++, Fourth Edition. 2014.*

Comment: A reference to the C standard might be more appropriate here rather than the C++ standard, even if it happens to be a rule common to both.