# Pointers to structures when declaring structure inside a structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a question regarding structures definition and pointers.

In the definition of linked list node structure we define the structure as follows:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;
```

Why whould we use this way of declaration instead of:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node next; //changed this line
}Node;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers)

Comment: Because you need to define something (completely) first before creating a variable of that type but you can have a pointer because the compiler already knows there is a `struct node` (the definition of which is incomplete) when you reach line `4`. The size of an incomplete data type is unknown to the compiler but the size of a pointer is always same for a given arch.

Comment: even if it's allowed to declare a struct inside itself then the size of the struct is undeterminable because it depends on how many levels of structs are nested

Comment: You can have a pointer to an incomplete type, but you cannot have an instance of an incomplete type.

Comment: If this was somehow possible to declare, the resulting struct would be infinitely recursive.  A node contains a node which contains a node, etc. forever.  It would be infinite size.

Comment: Note that the second code snippet implies infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A structure is defined after its closing brace. Until it a structure has an incomplete type. But a definition of a structure requires that all its members except a flexible array shall have complete types.

So in this declaration

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node next; //changed this line
}Node;
```

the data member next has an incomplete type.

From the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union speciﬁers)

> 8. ...The type is incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates 
>      the list, and complete thereafter.

and

> 3 **A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or
>   function type** (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
>   itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), except
>   that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
>   may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union
>   containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure)
>   shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array.

As for pointers then they always have complete types because their sizes are known.

Comment: Suppose you had a reference to another type of struct there?  Would it be preferable to have a pointer because otherwise the struct will take up more space?

Comment: @AlexLeibowitz It depends on the context. For example the structure node instead of the scalar data member data can contain an object of a structure type as for example person.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually we do that because, we avoid the recursive call.** Suppose think your second case. You call node inside a node itself. So what is the sizeof the node. sizeof(int) + sizeof(node). Then again for the node the size become sizeof(int)+sizeof(node). So this is a unstoppable recursive process. So we use the first case because avoid the recursive process. It just point to the object of same type structure.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to determine the size of whatever it is that comes its way.

This needs completeness in definition, so that a determined calculation can be made.

In the first case of self referential structure, we have a pointer. A pointer is os `struct node *` type has a definite size determined by the architecture.

In the second case - `struct node next`, what would be the size of next? Would it be the size of `struct node`? Okay, let's say it is, but then again - what is the size of `struct node`? Well, the answer is `sizeof(int) + sizeof(struct node)`. Okay, but then again... wait...what??... go back and read this entire para again, and realize the catch-22 situation here...

The compilers won't and don't appreciate this!