# C: why should I declare a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

It seems there are many questions of the form "should I declare X?" but not this specific one. I hope it is ok to ask this.

The title says it all: why should I declare a pointer? Even better: there are risks if I do not declare the pointer? Consider the following examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(int *ptr);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

  int a;
  int *PTRa;

  a = -1;
  PTRa = &a;


  func(PTRa);
  printf("%d\n", a);

  return 0;

}

void func(int *ptr)
{
  *ptr = 1;
  return;
}
```

I get `a=1`. In this case I would say the pointer is declared (and assigned as well): I have the line `int *PTRa;` (declaration) and the line `PTRa = &a;` (assignment). The results is correct. I don't get any warning.

Imagine now to replace the `main` with the following:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

  int a;

  a = -1;

  func(&a);
  printf("%d\n", a);

  return 0;

}
```

Here I do not declare the pointer but just give the address of `a` to `func`. The result is correct and I don't get warnings.

My understanding is that the two approaches are identical: `func` always gets the same input, the address of `a`. I would even dare to say that I feel the second approach to be better, as I feel it to be clearer and I feel the variable `PTRa` to be useless and somewhat redundant. However, I always see codes where the first approach is used and I have the feeling I will be told to do so. Why?

Comment: Both versions have exactly the same effect, and will probably be compiled the same with optimizations.  Whether you want the temporary variable is just a matter of which way you feel is more clear to read.

Comment: Q: why should I declare a pointer?  A: You shouldn't declare *ANYTHING* unless you *NEED* it.  1) `void func(int *ptr)` is silly: it should probably be `int func(int i)`, and return an int.  It *DEFINITELY* shouldn't have a (superfluous) "return". 2) declaring `PTRa` just so you can use it as a parameter to "func()" is silly.  Your second example, where you just call `func(&a);` is much better.

Comment: But  Nate Eldredge is 100% correct: `Whether you want the temporary variable is just a matter of which way you feel is more clear to read.`  There is no "one true answer".  Ultimately, it's just a matter of "preference".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: there's no point in declaring a pointer in your example. A pointer is just a variable that holds an address. The cleaner approach is to pass directly the address of the variable: `func(&a)` instead of doing one extra step and declaring `PTRa`.

Note that not all cases are this simple. For example, if you want to have an array of `int`s, but you want to be able to grow that array dynamically because you don't know how big it should be you have to declare a pointer:

```c
int count = ...; // get the count from the user, from a file, etc
int *list_of_ints = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
if (list_of_ints == NULL)
{
    // malloc failed.
    printf("Not enough memory!\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Now `list_of_ints` has enough space to store exactly `count` `int`s
```

EDIT: as @paulsm4 pointed out in a comment, the question [Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers/) is a great source of information related to this topic.

EDIT 2: one good reason to want a pointer to the address of a variable might be that you want a pointer inside a structure or array:

```c
struct foo
{
    int x;
};

struct bar
{
    int y;
    struct foo f;
};

struct bar b;
struct foo *ptr_foo = &b.f;
```

You can now work more easily with `b.f` because you're just working with a `struct foo`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware of `malloc` and how it works. My focus was specifically on pointers to a single address.

Comment: @GRquanti Then let's say you're making a linked list. You'll need pointers to nodes.

Comment: Nice! I am not aware of what a linked list is. I'll look at it. Thank you!

Comment: @GRquanti: I didn't realize your question was really that basic: "Q: What are pointers, and when/why should I use them?"  A: I encourage you to look at the replies in this thread: [Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/162988/421195)

Comment: @paulsm4 Oh, but I am aware of what pointers are and why to use them. I know the example I posted is not a good example of when a pointer should be used. You were correctly noting that in this case a function returning int works and is thus better. The example was just to express the syntax. The question, if you want, is "why people declare and assign pointers to a single address?". My current understanding is "there is no reason and a more compact syntax (as `func(&a)`) is probably better", as I originally suspected.

Comment: You're correct,  In general, "there's no reason...and the more compact syntax is probably better".  HOWEVER: this isn't an Absolute Rule.  Like  Nate Eldredge said (it's worth repeating): there are often very good reasons to create temp variables.  It's entirely a matter of preference.  Please *DO* read the responses in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers/162988#162988).  They're enlightening :)

Comment: As another example you may want or need a pointer inside and array or a structure. I added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case there's no benefit in creating a separate pointer variable.

It might be necessary in more complex cases, just like it's sometimes necessary to create variables of any other type.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on these complex cases?

Comment: @GRquanti See the other answer. We could give you more examples, but I suggest to just continue studying, and eventually you'll stumble upon them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From the title, I thought you're talking about pointer type, but actually, you are asking if declaring a variable is needed.

- Variable is a piece of memory, storing some numbers(bytes), and the type of the variable, indicating how you and your program interpret those bytes: integer? float? character? etc.
- Pointer is the memory address, it could be of a variable, or a function, or something else.
- A variable of pointer is a small area in the memory, storing the address of other(or even same) memory.
- You decide if you need an extra variable to store the pointer. It's the same to the decision that if you want a variable to store an integer:

```
int v = -1;
abs(v); // use variable
abs(-1); // use constant
```

Comment: I'm getting confused. My understanding is that pointer is a type, not a memory address. The type pointer stores a memory address, in the same way `int` stores a natural signed number and so on. A memory address, on the other hand, I would not say it is a type but rather a value. A value telling where the memory cell is, in the same way in `int a=-1` the `-1` is a value telling how much `a` amounts to.

Comment: @GRquanti That's correct. `int *` is your pointer type, `PTRa` is your variable, whose type is `int *`. `&a` is the constant.

Comment: Pointer stores address bytes, similar to int stores integer and char stores character as bytes in the memory.