# What is the point of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the point of pointers in C++ when I can just declare variables? When is it appropriate to use them?

Comment: this is subjective, argumentative and most likely a duplicate.

Comment: I think this is a valid question from a beginning C++ programmer.

I don't understand why it's been labeled subjective, and Babiker is doing his best to not be argumentative. Only if somebody were to lose karma by jumping in and saying something like "And that is why C++ is a bad language compared with <their favourite language>" would it become argumentative, and that isn't happening.

Comment: I agree, this is a good question that probably occurs to a lot of people getting started. If it's a duplicate, give a link to the original thread so the asker can find the answers.

Comment: Just one of the many questions if search SO is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers

http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+pointers

Comment: Thanks guys. I looked at some related question and i tried to word this question to be as direct as i can. i said "I know am very wrong about this" just so the title wouldn't seem argumentative. Then i addressed my main concern which is why not use the most obviousness thing to a beginner like my which is using variables.  Then to grasp the to concept i asked for some situations which i might not think of even after understanding the point in pointers.

Comment: It is subjective (i.e. What/When/Where/), but I don't think argumentative (i.e. Why) :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Pointers are best understood by C & C++'s differences in variable passing to functions.

Yes, you can pass either an entire variable or just a pointer to it (jargon is by value or reference, respectively).

But what if the variable is 20 meg array of bytes, like you decided to read an entire file in to one array?  Passing it by value would be foolish: why would you copy 20 megs for this operation, and if you end up modifying it (i.e. it's an out-parameter) you have to copy that 20 megs BACK?

Better is to just "point" to it.  You say, "here's a pointer to a big blob of memory".  And that little indirection saves a ton of time.

Once you understand that, everything else is basically the same.  Rearranging items in a list becomes just swapping pointers rather than copying every item around, you don't need to know how big things are when you start out, etc

Comment: Your comment makes sense (similar to my answer), but I am going to be picky about terminology. "Here's a reference to a big blob of memory", should really be "Here's a pointer to a big blob of memory". References have meaning in C++, and they are different from pointers (although, very similar and related, they are different).

Answer (score 16):

Pointers are most useful when dealing with data structures whose size and shape are not known at compile-time (think lists, trees, graphs, arrays, strings, ...).

**Edit**

These related answers might also help (the top answer in the second link is definitely worth a look):

[In C++ I Cannot Grasp Pointers and Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96285/in-c-i-cannot-grasp-pointers-and-classes)

[What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

Comment: Yes but i can't see how passing memory address can help with allocating memory!

Comment: You need some way to refer to a chunk of memory that has been dynamically allocated. You can't dynamically create a variable name, pointers allow memory to be referred to indirectly ("that fellow sitting at the end of the bar" versus "Sam").

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are also great for passing a mutable argument to a function so that the caller can "see the change". You may wonder, "but why not use a reference?". I like Google's argument:

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments

Comment: I used to be a fan of that idea but have gone off it recently.  I think I picked it up from "Code Complete".  Having used both, I don't think it makes any difference really because the caller can see a change is possible by the fact the parameter is a non-const reference.  It might make a difference if you tend to have large functions so when you see * or -> you know something outside the function is changing.  I think it's one of those things that should be standard accross a project, but which convention is used isn't all that important IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question when I was learning pointers, they just didn't seem important, but as you progress, you find out they are some times very useful.

Pointers are used often in programming situations. For example, when you reference an array by name, such as 

`array[i] = 3;`

The compiler is doing some fancy math that ends up turning that code into

(address of array) + (sizeof(array elements) * i) = 3;

They also make trees, linked-lists and other data structures possible, which you will find out as you learn more.

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic level, pointers allow you to associate disjoint blocks of memory.  A simple (contrived, admittedly) example of where pointers could help you would be in an algorithm that requires an array of 1000000000000 integers.  Such an array would be too large to fit within the RAM of the machine on which I am typing right now if I tried a definition such as:

```
int bigMatrix[1000000000000]; // I can't allocate this much contiguous memory
```

However, if I create a single array of pointers, I can keep the sub-arrays on a middle-sized disk array.

```
int *bigMatrix[1000000]; // Each pointer refers to a sub-array 
                         // of 1000000 elements on disk
```

Admittedly, I will have to write code to page in those sub-arrays if / when the user requires them, including hiding the array notation behind an accessor method.  That said, pointers allow me to create the ad-hoc associations that I need when I need them.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have a function that needs to return some amount of memory that isn't a set amount, such as reading from a file.

```
bool ReadDataFromFile(char** contents);
```

You would declare a char* contents and pass the address of that pointer to the function.  That function would then allocate the memory and your pointer would point to the contents upon return.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from efficiency and flexibility.The main point of pointers in C/C++ is that is how the hardware works, you could not wite a device driver, memory manager or efficient cache without using pointers somewhere along the line.

One of the main design goals for the first C compiler was to be a "portable assembly language" and to be able to do in a higher level language anything you could do with traditional assembly/machine code. This means being able to manipulate addresses directly - which is the point of pointers.

However following the KISS principle dont use pointers unless they really are making things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

From an architectural perspective, pointers are an economical way to model a 0 .. n relationship:

```
struct A {
  vector<const B *> *pBees;
  A() : pBees(nullptr) {}
  void notice_bee(const B *pB) { 
    if (!pBees)
      pBees = new vector<const B *>;
    pBees.push_back(pB)
  }
  ~A() { 
    delete pBees; // no need to test, delete nullptr is safe
  }
  size_t bees_noticed() { return pBees ? pBees->size : 0 }
};
```

If the vast majority of A objects will never need to pay attention to any B objects, there is no reason why every A object should have a zero-length vector.  Under Gnu C++ 4.0.1, sizeof(vector) is 12; sizeof(vector *) is 4.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you haven't yet learned about dynamic memory allocation.  There are two ways to allocate memory in C++: statically and dynamically.  You are already familiar with static allocation (i.e. - declaring variables).  This is great if you know at the time of writing your program exactly how many variables (or rather, memory) you need.

But what if you don't?  For example, let's say you're reading that contains a bunch of numbers you need to keep track of.  Why?  I don't know but that's not the point.

Well you could start with an array:

```
int array[100];
```

But what if there are more than 100 numbers in the file?  Eventually you'll want a more flexible solution:

```
int *array = new int[size];
// do stuff
delete [] array;
```

This gives you a lot more flexibility and lets you create more dynamic data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers store a memory address, so you would use them whenever you needed the memory address of something.
This can be useful for things such as memory management, knowing where your data is stored. My professor told us this is a beautiful thing for advance programs in terms of ensuring your data are contiguously located in memory (like c-style strings are).

Hope this is some form of help for you!

-Zen, a newbie at c++

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you write a text editor. In this case, you don't know the size of the document in advance. You might be tempted to declare something like

```
  char Document[10000];
```

but then certainly some day someone you will want to use your editor on a much larger document. So this attempt is futile; and what you need is a way to ask for new memory at *runtime* (instead of compile time).

The C++ way of doing this is using the operator new, which returns a pointer to the freshly allocated memory:

```
  char* pDocument = new char[getSizeOfDocument()];
```

(Note that this example is oversimplified. In real life, you would certainly not do it like this but instead use something like std::string and std::vector, which internally do this allocation for you.)

Answer (score -3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29):

> C++ references differ from pointers in
>   several essential ways:
>
> - It is not possible to refer directly to a reference object after
>     it is defined; any occurrence of its
>     name refers directly to the object it
>     references.
> - Once a reference is created, it cannot be later made to reference
>     another object; we say it cannot be
>     reseated. This is often done with
>     pointers.
> - References cannot be null, whereas pointers can; every reference refers
>     to some object, although it may or may
>     not be valid.
> - References cannot be uninitialized. Because it is impossible to
>     reinitialize a reference, they must be
>     initialized as soon as they are
>     created. In particular, local and
>     global variables must be initialized
>     where they are defined, and references
>     which are data members of class
>     instances must be initialized in the
>     initializer list of the class's
>     constructor.

With the above limitations, pointers are all you got as a lightweight container to reference object, especially if you are doing something with polymorphic or dynamic. Dynamic array of pure abstract class pointers to represent windows can be an example.

Since I am too lazy to think of an example of polymorphism I'll pull one from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/):

```
// pointers to base class
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CPolygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
  };

class CRectangle: public CPolygon {
  public:
    int area ()
      { return (width * height); }
  };

class CTriangle: public CPolygon {
  public:
    int area ()
      { return (width * height / 2); }
  };

int main () {
  CRectangle rect;
  CTriangle trgl;
  CPolygon * ppoly1 = &rect;
  CPolygon * ppoly2 = &trgl;
  ppoly1->set_values (4,5);
  ppoly2->set_values (4,5);
  cout << rect.area() << endl;
  cout << trgl.area() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In the above code, pointer `CPolygon *` is used to reference `CRectangle` object and `CTriangle` object.

Comment: Pointers aren't necessary or even preferred in that example - references are.