# Using class pointers vs instance

Tags: c++, class, pointers

What I don't understand is what is the difference between using a pointer to a class and generating a new instance of it. It's just for performance? Here I made a class and made m the pointer to the class and n the instance of the class.
And another question: can i make a pointer the class and use another constructor? like `myClass* p(7); p->afis();` ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myClass
{
    int a;
public:
    myClass(void);
    myClass(int);
    void afis();
    ~myClass(void);
};

myClass::myClass(void)
{
    a = 5;
}

myClass::myClass(int nr)
{
    a = nr;
}

void myClass::afis()
{
    cout << a;
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
}

int main()
{
    myClass* m;                                     //<--
    m->afis();

    myClass n(7);                                   //<--
    n.afis();

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Have a look here for understanding pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96285/in-c-i-cannot-grasp-pointers-and-classes

Comment: You meant `myClass* m = new MyClass;`, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
myClass* m;
```

is just an pointer to the type `myClass` it does not point to any valid object, dereferecing such a pointer is **Undefined Behavior**.

An Undefined Behavior means that your program is invalid and it may seem to work or it may crash or it may show any weird behavior, all safe bets are off. So just because your program works does not mean it is safe and it will always work.

To write a valid program you will have to make the pointer point to a valid object.
For example:

```
myClass obj;
myClass*m = &obj;
```

In the second case:

```
 myClass n(7);
```

It creates an object `n` of the type `myClass` by calling the constructor of `myClass` which takes one argument of the type `int`.
This is a valid way of creating an object.

Answer (score 4):

> can i make a pointer the class and use another constructor

Making a pointer doesn't call a constructor. The pointer is uninitialized until you set it to the address of some object (maybe a brand new object created with `new`).

> ```
> myClass* m;                                     //<--
> m->afis();
> ```

This is undefined behavior, you have a wild pointer because `m` hasn't been initialized.

Better:

```
std::unique_ptr<myClass> m(new myClass(constructor, args, here));                                     
m->afis();
```

Comment: then why after i say this myClass* m; m->afis(); it points 5 on the screen?

Comment: @Dementor: It's undefined behavior.  Anything can happen.  It could print `5`.  It could crash.  It could overwrite all your files.  It could e-mail obscene pictures to your grandmother.

Comment: Using freestore here is not needed at all. All one needs here is a simple local object.I know for a fact that you very well know that, I am wondering why this example then?

Comment: What does `afis` mean?

Comment: @BenVoigt, Haha, good one! I laughed at that so hard :)