# Pointer to a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

**Duplicate:**

> [Uses for multiple levels of pointer dereferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences)

I have a question about C and pointers.

I know when I would need a pointer, and even when I might need a pointer to a pointer.
An example would be if I had a linked list, and I wanted to write a function that would remove an element of that list,  to do so I would need to send a pointer to the pointer of the head of the list.

How about a pointer to a pointer to a pointer?  Would there ever be a situation where that would be needed?  Extra points if you have some sample code so I can really get my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

A vector is *, an array is **, a volume is ***, a timespace is ****.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely rare, but you could imagine some kind of reference counting scenario, where you needed to get to some other object's address of pointers and change it.

Answer (score 0):

What about a function to remove an element from a linked list in an array of linked lists, or a function to remove an element from a linked list in an array of arrays of link... you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are arrays in a sense.  Here's a straightforward scenario.  Say you were building a text editor.  Lines and columns are both dynamic.

You might have an "array" of lines, and since they're dynamic, that would be a pointer.  Then your columns would also be dynamic and might be contained inside of your line array.  So in essence:

```
char **lines;
```

You would have to malloc your line first before adding characters, but this could provide a very crude means of an editor.

```
lines = malloc(num_of_lines_in_my_file);
lines[0] = malloc(num_of_chars_for_line_1);
```

Certainly not beautiful code, but hopefully it helps a bit to answer the question.