# How can I allocate memory and return it (via a pointer-parameter) to the calling function?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have some code in a couple of different functions that looks something like this:

```
void someFunction (int *data) {
  data = (int *) malloc (sizeof (data));
}

void useData (int *data) {
  printf ("%p", data);
}

int main () {
  int *data = NULL;

  someFunction (data);

  useData (data);

  return 0;
}
```

`someFunction ()` and `useData ()` are defined in separate modules (*.c files).

The problem is that, while malloc works fine, and the allocated memory is usable in `someFunction`, the same memory is not available once the function has returned.

An example run of the program can be seen [here](http://a_m0d.codepad.org/ATOYNQYw), with output showing the various memory addresses.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here, and how I can get this code to work?

---

EDIT: So it seems like I need to use double pointers to do this - how would I go about doing the same thing when I actually need to *use* double pointers? So e.g. data is

```
int **data = NULL; //used for 2D array
```

Do I then need to use triple pointers in function calls?

Comment: Yes, you would need triple pointers then

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You want to use a pointer-to-pointer:

```
void someFunction (int **data) {
  *data = malloc (sizeof (int));
}

void useData (int *data) {
  printf ("%p", data);
}

int main () {
    int *data = NULL;

    someFunction (&data);

    useData (data);

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Why? Well, you want to change your pointer `data` in the main function. In C, if you want to change something that's passed in as a parameter (and have that change show up in the caller's version), you have to pass in a pointer to whatever you want to change. In this case, that "something you want to change" is a pointer -- so to be able to change that pointer, you have to use a pointer-to-pointer...

Note that on top of your main problem, there was another bug in the code: `sizeof(data)` gives you the number of bytes required to store the pointer (4 bytes on a 32-bit OS or 8 bytes on a 64-bit OS), whereas you really want the number of bytes required to store *what the pointer points to* (an `int`, i.e. 4 bytes on most OSes). Because typically `sizeof(int *)>=sizeof(int)`, this probably wouldn't have caused a problem, but it's something to be aware of. I've corrected this in the code above.

Here are some useful questions on pointers-to-pointers:

[How do pointer to pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

[Uses for multiple levels of pointer dereferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences)

Comment: I suggest not calling it a "double pointer" - too easily confused with a "pointer to double".

Comment: "double pointer" and "triple pointer" are actually quite common terms

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- even though I agree "double pointer" is quite common, I've eliminated it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Personally I'd use `sizeof **data` as opposed to `sizeof (int)`, but otherwise this nails it.

Comment: Why do need not free it here? Like free the memory? I did something similar freeing the memory does not work. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74088030/why-is-freeing-the-memory-after-printing-the-string-messing-up-the-print-result`

Answer (score 12):

A common pitfall especially if you moved form Java to C/C++

Remember when you passing a pointer, it's pass by value i.e the value of the pointer is copied. It's good for making changes to data pointed by the pointer but any changes to the pointer itself is just local since it a copy!!

The trick is to use pass the pointer by reference since you wanna change it i.e malloc it etc.

**pointer --> will scare a noobie C programmer ;)

Comment: Hello, I don't understand the "pass by value" part. A pointer is an adress right ? so when you pass an address to the function how could it be a copy ?

Comment: A pointer is a type whose value is a memory address. We use this pointer type to point to other objects in memory.
   
Let's say you pass a pointer p{val: 0x1234}  to a function. (Remember pointers are objects too so they also have an address, say 0x8888)
- The function will get the pointer and will be able to access the object at 0x1234, however the pointer pointing to this address is not the same pointer as pointer at 0x8888, it's a copy and just has the same value! 
- This is similar to passing an int by value. It get's copied.

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass a pointer to the pointer if you want to modify the pointer.

ie. :

```
void someFunction (int **data) {
  *data = malloc (sizeof (int)*ARRAY_SIZE);
}
```

edit : 
Added ARRAY_SIZE, at some point you have to know how many integers you want to allocate.

Comment: The `sizeof` should be `sizeof(**data)` (or simply `sizeof(int)`); this bug was already in the original code.

Comment: dont cast the return value of malloc - http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1047673478

Answer (score 3):

That is because pointer data is passed by value to `someFunction`.

```
int *data = NULL;
//data is passed by value here.
someFunction (data); 
//the memory allocated inside someFunction  is not available.
```

Pointer to pointer  or  return the allocated pointer would solve the problem.

```
void someFunction (int **data) {
  *data = (int *) malloc (sizeof (data));
}


int*  someFunction (int *data) {
  data = (int *) malloc (sizeof (data));
return data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

someFunction() takes its parameter as int*. So when you call it from main(),  a copy of the value you passed created. Whatever you are modifying inside the function is this copy and hence the changes will not be reflected outside. As others suggested, you can use int** to get the changes reflected in data. Otherway of doing it is to return int* from someFunction().

Answer (score 3):

Apart from using the doublepointer technique, if there's only 1 return param needed rewrite is as following:

```
 int *someFunction () {
   return (int *) malloc (sizeof (int *));
 }
```

and use it:

```
 int *data = someFunction ();
```

Comment: No, I just did that to simplify things - can't return it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the general pattern for allocating memory in a function and returning the pointer via parameter:

```
void myAllocator (T **p, size_t count)
{
  *p = malloc(sizeof **p * count);
}
...
void foo(void)
{
  T *p = NULL;
  myAllocator(&p, 100);
  ...
}
```

Another method is to make the pointer the function's return value (my preferred method):

```
T *myAllocator (size_t count)
{
  T *p = malloc(sizeof *p * count);
  return p;
}
...
void foo(void)
{
  T *p = myAllocator(100);
  ...
}
```

Some notes on memory management:

1. The best way to avoid problems with memory management is to avoid memory management; don't muck with dynamic memory unless you *really* need it.
2. Do not cast the result of malloc() unless you're using an implementation that predates the 1989 ANSI standard or you intend to compile the code as C++.  If you forget to include stdlib.h or otherwise don't have a prototype for malloc() in scope, casting the return value will supress a valuable compiler diagnostic.
3. Use the size of the object being allocated instead of the size of the data type (i.e., `sizeof *p` instead of `sizeof (T)`); this will save you some heartburn if the data type has to change (say from int to long or float to double).  It also makes the code read a little better IMO.
4. Isolate memory management functions behind higher-level allocate and deallocate functions; these can handle not only allocation but also initialization and errors.

Comment: An advantage of the double-indirect pointer approach is that it can return status information beyond pass/fail, and if pointers are always `null` whenever they're not valid it can implement "allocate if needed" semantics.  Unfortunately, even on platforms where all pointers have the same representation code will need to use ugly `malloc` calls to prevent obtuse compilers from getting tripped up by aliasing (a sane compiler should recognize that a call like `doSomething((void**)&ptr)` is likely to modify ptr) even if `ptr` is something other than a `void*`).

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to modifying the pointer i.e. from "data == Null" to "data == 0xabcd"some other memory you allocated. So to modify data that you need pass the address of data i.e. &data.

```
void someFunction (int **data) {
  *data = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replying to your additional question you edited in:

'*' denotes a pointer to something. So '**' would be a pointer to a pointer to something, '***' a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to something, etc.

The usual interpretation of 'int **data' (if data is not a function parameter) would be a pointer to list of int arrays (e.g. 'int a [100][100]').

So you'd need to first allocate your int arrays (I am using a direct call to malloc() for the sake of simplicity):

```
data = (int**) malloc(arrayCount); //allocate a list of int pointers
for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) //assign a list of ints to each int pointer
   data [i] = (int*) malloc(arrayElemCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using double pointer we can just allocate a new pointer and just return it, no need to pass double pointer because it is not used anywhere in the function.

Return `void *` so can be used for any type of allocation.

```
void *someFunction (size_t size) {
    return  malloc (size);
}
```

and use it as:

```
int *data = someFunction (sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let me call the above single pointer parameter p
and the double pointer pp (pointing to p).

In a function, the object that p points to can be changed and the change goes out of
the function. However, if p itself is changed, the change does not
leave the function.

Unfortunately, malloc by its own nature, typically
changes p. That is why the original code does not work. 
The correction (58) uses the pointer pp pointing to p. in the corrected
function, p is changed but pp is not. Thus it worked.