# BST - inserting + C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to work on a binary search tree data structure, but I cannot seem to accomplish inserting anything into the tree.  Every time my program calls the insert function, it believes there is nothing in tree.  Here are the 2 classes:

```
template<typename T>
class TreeNode{
public:
    T m_data;
    TreeNode* m_right;
    TreeNode* m_left;
    TreeNode<T>(const T& data, TreeNode<T>* right, TreeNode<T>* left) : m_data(data), m_right(right), m_left(left){};
};

template<typename T>
class MyBSTree : public AbstractBSTree<T>{
protected:
    TreeNode<T>* m_root;
    int m_size;
```

And here is the function:

```
    void rec_insert(TreeNode<T>* root, const T& x){
        if(root == NULL){
            cout << "Inserting here" << endl;
            TreeNode<T>* tmp = new TreeNode<T>(x, NULL, NULL);
            root = tmp;
        }
        else if(x < root -> m_data){
            cout << "Inserting left" << endl;
            rec_insert(root -> m_left, x);  
        }
        else if(x > root -> m_data){
            cout << "Inserting right" << endl;
            rec_insert(root -> m_right, x);
        }
        if(root == NULL)
            cout << "WHAT IS HAPPENING?" << endl;
        cout << "resizing" << endl;
        m_size++;
    };
```

The output for inserting a couple of items is this:

```
Inserting here
resizing
Inserting here
resizing
```

I really have no clue what is going on here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you changed value of root inside your function but it will not reflect in your calling function. that is your problem.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398307/how-can-i-allocate-memory-and-return-it-via-a-pointer-parameter-to-the-calling

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a bit of research on pass by reference and pass by value.

You pass a pointer into your insert method - you can only change the value of `root` locally - any change you make won't persist beyond the function call. You need to pass by reference to allow `root` to be changed and see that change outside the `rec_insert()` method.

Another approach may be to refactor your code to return the root value from `rec_insert()`.