# How to modify a heap pointer from a function

Tags: c, pointers, scope, heap-memory

How can I change a heap allocated global pointer from within a function? Here is what I am working with, (call to `modify_p` seg faults and I can't see much in the debugger):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *p;

void set_p(int *p, int sz) {
        p = malloc(sz * sizeof(int));
}

void modify_p(int *p) {
    p[0] = 2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    set_p(p, 3);
    modify_p(p);
    //printf("%d\n", p[0]);
    // should print 2   
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398307/how-can-i-allocate-memory-and-return-it-via-a-pointer-parameter-to-the-calling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you pass a copy of `p` to `set_p`. So the original `p` is never modified and never points to valid memory, and the copy is lost at the end of `set_p`, leaking the memory. Instead, pass a pointer to `p` (so a pointer to a pointer), like this:

```
void set_p(int **p, int sz) {
    *p = malloc(sz * sizeof(int));
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
set_p(&p, 3);
```

Then you get the expected result.

Comment: Alternatively, don't pass `p` at all and use the global variable directly.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *p;

void set_p(int sz) {
        p = malloc(sz * sizeof(int));
}

void modify_p() {
    p[0] = 2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    set_p(3);
    modify_p();
    printf("%d\n", p[0]);
    // should print 2   
    return 0;
}
```

As `p` is declared outside of any function, you can write directly to it. When you do `set_p(p, 3);`, the `set_p` function will have it's local copy of the variable.

If you want to change what a pointer points to, you have to pass the address of the pointer (as shown by Blaze).

Comment: `modify_p(p); --> modify_p();`

Comment: @MayurK Strictly speaking, invoking `modify_p(p)` also works because the function actually takes an unspecified number of args. Anyways, modified to keep things simple.

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry I didn't mention that `modify_p` should really have been `modify(int *p, int sz)` because it needs to work for more than one pointer.