# Duplicate String in C

Tags: c

I have tried to write a function in C that duplicates a string n times. Below is my code, but this does not work. Can someone help me and tell me where I am making a mistake? It should come out something like this:

**Input: 4 House
Output: HouseHouseHouse**

```
char * repeat(char *str, int times)
 { char *ret = calloc(times, (strlen(str) + 1));
   while (times-- > 0)
     strcat(ret,str);
     char *b;
   b = repeat(str,times);
   printf("%s",b);
   return 0; }
```

Comment: *One* "not work" part is because you must decide to use *either* loops *or* recursion. Not both.

Comment: *Another* not work part is because you *always* return a null pointer from the function.

Comment: And input 4 House, but out put House only 3 times

Comment: You should always include what "does not work" means. Provide input and actual output together with expected output. Is your output expected output or current output?

Comment: Your `repeat` does an infinite recursion,

Comment: Here's some advice for doing recursive code - Basically you _always_ need to handle two cases: 1) the base case and 2) the recursive case ("iteration").

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this code? I just removed the recursion and added an extra argument output, which will be allocated inside the function repeat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void repeat(char *input, char**ouput, int times)
 { *ouput = calloc(times, (strlen(input) + 1));
   while (times-- > 0)
     strcat(*ouput,input);
   printf("%s",*ouput);
 } 
   
int main()
{
    void repeat(char *input, char**ouput, int times);
    char * ouput;
    repeat("hello",&ouput,5);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It worked, but how can i edit the code without an extra argument output? I would like to have the function with two arguments. Like this: repeat(char *str, int times). Is this possible?

Comment: the allocation will be done inside the function repeat, the system will clean up the data of the function after exit it, so it will be dangerous to return the output as a pointer and use it in your main function you need to keep the input, output and the number of copies as argument and return the length of new output

Comment: What exactly is the problem with a function returning an allocated pointer?  How does that differ from assigning to a pointer to pointer?  The comment is give erroneous advice.  Sadly, comments can't be downvoted.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398307/how-can-i-allocate-memory-and-return-it-via-a-pointer-parameter-to-the-calling