# C triple dereferencing

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uses for multiple levels of pointer dereferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences)

I have used functions with doubly dereferenced pointers (**var) to return values. However, I was recently asked a question to figure out a use-case where a triple dereferencing (***var) may be needed. I couldn't think of any practical scenario. Does anyone have any experience here?

Comment: There are datastructures that use nth order dereferencing.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link. Much was answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a [tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor), then you would need triple dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a two-dimensional pointer array used to referencing a general two-dimensional array, you would need triple dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

A two dimensional array containing pointers to functions.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a handle.

Comment: I only see *two* layers of indirection there, not three.

Comment: @bitmask: What is a handle (As in a computer science handle not a Windows Handle)? Once you answer that question you will understand why this-is a three indirections.

Comment: It might be useful to clarify in your post. Perhaps.

Comment: @bitmask: If you understand computer science fundamentals then it it is crystal clear. If you don't then there is little point clarifying.