# How do I iterate over a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

Lets say I have the following variables:

```
char c[] = "ABC";
char *ptr = &c;
char **ptr2 = &ptr;
```

I know I can iterate over a pointer to an array of char, this way:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf("TEST******************, %c\n", ptr[i]);
}
```

How do I iterate over a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Just a FYI: the `&c` is a value of type `char (*)[4]` (pointer to array of 4 characters): `c` does not decay to a pointer to its first element in the expression `ptr = &c;`. Your compiler should have warned about incompatible types in the assignment ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf("TEST******************, %c\n", (*ptr2)[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose:

```
  6   char c[] = "ABC";
  7 
  8   char *ptr   = &c;
  9   char *ptr2  = ptr;       
 10   char **ptr3 = &ptr;
```

[image]

In this scenario:

- `ptr` represents an *address of `c`*
- `ptr2` represents an address of `ptr`. *A pointer to a pointer*
- `ptr3` is a *value* stored in `ptr`, which is an address of `c`.

`**ptr3=&ptr` means - Take address of `ptr`, look inside and assign its value (not address) to `ptr3`

If I understood your question correctly, you need to use pointers to pointers: `ptr2` in my example instead of `ptr3`

If so, you can access elements like :

```
ptr2[0] = A
ptr2[1] = B
ptr2[2] = C
```

For the record the following will yeld the same results. Try it.

```
 12   printf ("===>>> %x\n", ptr2);
 13   printf ("===>>> %x\n", *ptr3);
```

Good discussion for your reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences)

Answer (score 1):

If I did not misunderstand your question, this code should make a job

```
printf("TEST******************, %c\n", (*ptr2)[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

let me give an example,

```
char **str; // double pointer declaration
str = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*2);
str[0]=(char *)"abcdefgh";   // or *str  is also fine instead of str[0]
str[1]=(char *)"lmnopqrs";

while(*str!=NULL)
{
    cout<<*str<<endl; // prints the string
    str++;
}
free(str[0]);
free(str[1]);
free(str);
```

or one more best example which you can understand.
here i have used 2 for loops because i am iterating over each character of the array of strings.

```
char **str = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*3); // it allocates 8*3=24 Bytes
str[0]=(char *)"hello";    // 5 bytes 
str[1]=(char *)"world";    // 5 bytes
// totally 10 bytes used out of 24 bytes allocated
while(*str!=NULL)   // this while loop is for iterating over strings
{
    while(**str!=NULL)   // this loop is for iterating characters of each string
    {
         cout<<**str;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    str++;
}
free(str[0]);
free(str[1]);
free(str);
```