# What is the meaning of "a = new arr ***[num];"?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Is it possible pointers "***" is placed between arr and []?
What implies this line?

Comment: possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you put this inside a compilable `int main()` function in order to afford more clarity please?

Comment: You can [check it yourself](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). Try getting used to checking that site before you ask something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
a = new arr***[num];
```

allocate an array of `num` pointers to pointers to pointers to `arr`, and make `a` point to that memory.

The type of `a` have to be `arr****`. Which is just silly.